# convert datetime error in SQL Server (2005)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created two functions to work with ISO 8601 dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IPUTILS_STR_TO_ISODATE (
    @isostr VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, @isostr, 126);
END;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION IPUTILS_ISODATE_TO_STR (
  @date VARCHAR(30))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(30); 
    SET @result =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @date, 126);
    RETURN @result;
END;
GO
```

I don't get them working correct for some reason. If I do:

```
select dbo.IPUTILS_ISODATE_TO_STR(dbo.IPUTILS_STR_TO_ISODATE('1965-04-28T12:47:43'));
```

I get:

```
apr 28 1965 12:47PM
```

instead of:

```
1965-04-28T12:47:43
```

if I do:

```
select convert(VARCHAR(30), dbo.IPUTILS_STR_TO_ISODATE('1965-04-28T12:47:43'), 126);
```

I get:

```
1965-04-28T12:47:43
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not testing these functions individually first and *then* in combination? If you do test them individually you will likely see the problem ;-). Check the datatype of the `@date` input parameter on the `IPUTILS_ISODATE_TO_STR` function: it is `VARCHAR(30)` instead of `DATETIME`.

Having the incorrect datatype for the input parameter means that an implicit conversion from a real DATETIME into VARCHAR, but *without* a specified "style", is happening as the value comes into the function. This is the same as doing `CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @date)`. And the result of this implicit conversion (i.e. the value stored in `@date`) is being sent to the `SET @result =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @date, 126);` line.

Also, I would suggest *not* doing this in the first place (i.e. creating either of these functions) if they are going to be used in SELECT statements or WHERE clauses. Using the CONVERT() function in those places is repetitive, but also *much* faster. T-SQL scalar UDFs and Multiline TVFs do not perform well and you can slow down your queries by using them. In this particular case there is no real computation / formula being done so you aren't really gaining much outside of not needing to remember the "style" number. Also, T-SQL functions invalidate the query from getting a parallel execution plan. But if these are just being used in simple `SET` statements to manipulate a variable that is being used in a query, then that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks srutzky, i should have teste better before asking te question. Thanks as well for the tips. I'll keep that in mind, Repel